# Problems reading from Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

I've just installed an Oracle express database and am trying to read some data from a table I've put in there:

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=localhost:1521/xe;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SYSTEM;Password=SYSTEMPASSWORD"))
{
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Firstname = 'John'", conn);
    conn.Open();
    OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    try
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string strResult = reader.GetString(0);
        }
    }
    catch (OracleException oex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(oex.Message, "Oracle error");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

On the `while (reader.Read())` it just quits since the reader does not hold any data. What is wrong? `Connectionstring`? I've run the same `SELECT` in the commandprompt tool that is installed with Oracle express and it works fine.

Comment: are you sure connection is properly opened and ExecuteReader works with no exceptions? did you put a breakpoint and checked value of reader object after assignment and before entering the while loop?

Comment: Is this select returns any rows if you will run it in sqlplus or any other tool?

Comment: Try the select without the WHERE clause

Comment: I'm not sure why you've decided to add a bounty to this question instead of answering the questions others have asked of you.  Have a read of the bounty FAQ - the word 'bounty' in the banner below takes you straight to it.

Comment: @Jason94 Never catch System.Exception - it could be an OutOfMemoryException or a StackOverflowException which can cause unexpected side effects later on.

Comment: To rule out the query from being the problem could you change it to "Select user from dual". If that also fails to return you can at least assume you have a bigger problem than the query itself. If it works then you know somehow that query isn't working but your connection is good.

Comment: Gosh all these silly suggestions, put the `OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();` in the Try-Catch and tell us the Exception message, or the error code if its a second chance exception...

Comment: I don't understand why you would offer a bounty an don't respond to questions placed in commentaries or to suggestions in the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing to do when connection to any system is see/test if it succeeded and after that continue. Without these simple kinds of tests your application is bound to behave like a time-bomb. A bit of defensive programming will make your projects a lot easier to debug.
Not really the answer you are looking for but currently the state of the connection is not clear at query execution time.

Answer (score 2):

Table Persons is in the SYSTEM schema?
Run another query, like 'select object_name from user_objects' and give us updates with what you've done.

Comment: or just execute SELECT * FROM DUAL

Answer (score 1):

It´s been a long time since I don't use Oracle with .Net, but I don´t see which database you use (is it "xe"?). With SQL Server I specify it with INITIAL CATALOG in the connection string. Here you have different connection strings to try: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle. I would also start by openning the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party but...

I had the same problem accessing a view and it turned out the appropriate privileges weren't granted on it. Once I'd granted the SELECT privilege to my user id I could get my data.